# How to optimize treeview & datagridview?

Tags: xml, winforms, powershell, datagridview, treeview

We have a Windows form written in PowerShell. The form shows three treeviews and one datagridview. Inside each treeview are ca. 100-1500 nodes and some childnodes. The datagridview holds about 500 items.

The data to display is stored inside a XML file.

```xml
<Config>
    <treeview1>
        <ID ID="1" Data="" />
    </treeview1>
    <treeview2>
        <ID ID="1" Data="" />
    </treeview2>
    <treeview3>
        <ID ID="1" Data="" />
    </treeview3>
    <datagridview>
        ID ID="1" Data="" />
    </datagridview>
</Config>
```

To load the the treeviews and the datagridview we use a `foreach` loop.

```bsh
foreach ($XmlNode in $Xml.Config.treeview1.ID)
{
    if (!($TreeView.Nodes.ContainsKey($XmlNode.Data)))
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode]$TreeViewNode = $null
        $TreeViewNode = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
        $TreeViewNode.Text = $XmlNode.Data
        $TreeViewNode.Name = $XmlNode.Data
        $TreeViewNode.Tag = $XmlNode.ID
        $TreeViewNode.ImageIndex = 1
        $TreeViewNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1

        $TreeView.Nodes.Add($TreeViewNode)
    }
}
```

Now we face two problems:

1. Form opening and loading data is slow.
2. Scrolling through the datagridview is slow and lags.

Are there any suggestions to speed up the data loading and the datagridview scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly load the treeview or datagridview items / nodes with the `foreach` I noticed some permormance benefits if I create first of all an array of items and load them all together with `AddRange`.
Here an example with a `ListView`:

```
function Add-ListViewItem
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Void])]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListView]$ListView,
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [PSCustomObject]$Items,
        [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]$Append
    )
    begin
    {
        $ListView.Update()
    }
    process
    {
        #Clear listview
        if (!$Append)
        {
            $ListView.Items.Clear()
        }

        #Create the ListViewItem
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]]$ListViewItems = $null
        foreach ($Item in $Items)
        {

            $ListViewItem = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
            $ListViewItem.Text = $Item.NoteProperty1
            $ListViewItem.SubItems.Add($Item.NoteProperty2)

            $ListViewItems += $ListViewItem
        }

        #Add the items to the listview
        if ($ListViewItems -ne $null)
        {
            $ListView.Items.AddRange($ListViewItems)
        }

    }
    end
    {
        $ListView.EndUpdate()
    }
}
```